# How to write a shell script restart apache if `server reached MaxClients`

Tags: shell-script, logs, apache-httpd

Recently, my blog always shutdown, it use `centos6.2+apache2.2+mysql5.5+php5.3`.
I have raised `MaxClients` in `httpd.conf`, but less useful.

So is it possible to write a shell script (Run with crontab every 10 minutes), to read the `httpd/error_log`, if the last message `preg_match` `sending a SIGTERM` do restart apache automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the log files can be pretty tricky. Rather than try to do that, you'd probably be better off using a script such as this one which can run from a crontab entry. This script will attempt to access the server, if it's unsuccessful then it will restart Apache.

#### Script

*Source of script: [bash script to restart Apache automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168518/bash-script-to-restart-apache-automatically)*

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script that checks whether apache is still up, and if not:
# - e-mail the last bit of log files
# - kick some life back into it
# -- Thomas, 20050606

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
THEDIR=/tmp/apache-watchdog
EMAIL=yourself@example.com
mkdir -p $THEDIR

if ( wget --timeout=30 -q -P $THEDIR http://localhost/robots.txt )
then
    # we are up
    touch ~/.apache-was-up
else
    # down! but if it was down already, don't keep spamming
    if [[ -f ~/.apache-was-up ]]
    then
        # write a nice e-mail
        echo -n "apache crashed at " > $THEDIR/mail
        date >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Access log:" >> $THEDIR/mail
        tail -n 30 /var/log/apache2_access/current >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Error log:" >> $THEDIR/mail
        tail -n 30 /var/log/apache2_error/current >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        # kick apache
        echo "Now kicking apache..." >> $THEDIR/mail
        /etc/init.d/apache2 stop >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        killall -9 apache2 >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        /etc/init.d/apache2 start >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        # send the mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Good luck troubleshooting!" >> $THEDIR/mail
        mail -s "apache-watchdog: apache crashed" $EMAIL < $THEDIR/mail
        rm ~/.apache-was-up
    fi
fi

rm -rf $THEDIR
```

#### Paths

The paths to the stop/start scripts will need to be adjusted accordingly based on where your distro has installed Apache. Lines like this one:

```
        /etc/init.d/apache2 start >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
```

If you're on CentOS will be like this:

```
        /etc/init.d/httpd start >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
```

#### Name of Executable

The same goes with the `killlall` lines. The name of the executable on CentOS is `httpd`.

#### The crontab entry

This cron will need to be run as root so that it has the appropriate permissions to stop/start Apache.